# How to prove/disprove that a map is a covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Im right now learning some algebraic topology, and i have a problem with showing, that given maps are covering spaces. I understand what a covering space is "definitionwise", but not how I can best proceed in showing that something actually is a cover.

For example, how would I proceed if i want to show, that this
$$S^1 \rightarrow S^1, z \mapsto z^n$$
is indeed a covering space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be the given function.

For each $x$ in $S^1$ we must demonstrate some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a set of disjoint copies of $U$ (each homeomorphic to $U$ by the appropriate restriction of $f$).

Consider any sufficiently small open interval containing $x$.  Clearly, for this $U$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint collection of $n$ copies of $U$ (each scaled down by a factor of $n$), and each local restriction of $f$ is a homeomorphism, as required.